# ReactPHP - Close disconnected connection

Tags: php, sockets, reactphp

I am using ReactPHP for TCP listener component. This component listens for incoming connections and exchanges data with them. $connections array is updated as clients connect/disconnect from listener.

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$connections = [];
$socket = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$socket->on('connection', function ($conn) use($loop, $db){
    global $connections;
    $connections[] = $conn;
    $conn->on('data', function ($data) use ($conn,$loop, $db) {
        global $connections;
        // ...
        // ...
        $conn->on('close', function ($conn) use($loop, $db){
            global $connections;
            if(($key = array_search($conn, $connections, true)) !== FALSE) {
                unset($connections[$key]);
            }   
        });
});
$socket->listen(16555, '127.0.0.1');
$loop->run();
```

If client is connected via telnet 'close' will be emitted so I can remove closed connection from $connection array. 
However, I have problem with some devices that connect to my listener too. If I turn off device 'close' will not be emitted.
I tried to solve problem with periodical timer:

```
$loop->addPeriodicTimer(10, function () use($db, $loop){
    global $connections;
    foreach($connections as $c) {
        $remoteAddress = $c->getRemoteAddress();
        $metaData = @stream_get_meta_data($c->stream);
        if(!$metaData) {
            if(($key = array_search($c, $connections, true)) !== FALSE) {
                unset($connections[$key]);
            }   
        }
    }
});
```

But seems that it is not reliable enough. Function stream_get_meta_data returns valid metadata array even though client is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

It is some while since this question was asked, but I've found what works for me is to use an SplObjectStorage() to be the connection pool. This is a collection which doesn't (externally) have an index. It works quite well for connections.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php

I think the source of your original problem is that you are unsetting an element within a foreach, which does not automatically update the keys, and you can end up with your objects out of sequence.

In order to iterate over a collection (or an array) with code where you may be removing one or more elements while within the loop, it can be safer to use **clone**.

So where your pool is:

```
$connections_pool = new SplObjectStorage();
```

To iterate you would do (per your original request)

```
$loop->addPeriodicTimer(10, function () use($db, $loop){
    global $connections_pool;
    foreach(clone($connections_pool) as $c) {
        $remoteAddress = $c->getRemoteAddress();
        $metaData = @stream_get_meta_data($c->stream);
        if(!$metaData) {
            $connections_pool->offsetUnset($c);            
        }
    }
});
```